# How can I show the legend in my PieChart?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, recharts

so I'm trying to show the name of the colors in my PieChart, so what I'm trying to get here is the name and put it as a legend, [image]

Json

```
    {
        "choice": "20-29 yrs. old",
        "count": 4
    },
    {
        "choice": "30-39 yrs. old",
        "count": 2
    },
    {
        "choice": "40-49 yrs. old",
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "choice": "50-59 yrs. old",
        "count": 2
    },
    {
        "choice": "60 yrs. old and above",
        "count": 1
    }.
```

This is how I render the PieChart.

```
 <ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height={400}>
    <PieChart>
      <Pie
        data={data}
        cx="50%"
        cy="50%"
        labelLine={false}
        label={renderCustomizedLabel}
        outerRadius={150}
        fill="#8884d8"
        dataKey="count"
      >
        {data.map((entry, index) => (
          <Cell key={`cell-${index}`} fill={COLORS[index % COLORS.length]} />
        ))}
      </Pie>
      <Legend verticalAlign="bottom" />
    </PieChart>
    
  </ResponsiveContainer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need a **payload** property from the [Legend](https://recharts.org/en-US/api/Legend). To form legend payload you can go this way:

```
const legendPayload = data.map((entry, index) => ({
  id: index,
  type: 'square',
  value: entry.choice,
  color: COLORS[index % COLORS.length],
}));
```

Then pass it inside payload prop:

```
<Legend verticalAlign="bottom" payload={legendPayload} />
```